# save input value despite the page being refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cookies, input

I am a new Programmer and I'm really interested in learning JavaScript. I was making an input box where the user enter a amount. I want it to saved until the user nextTime edit/update it, but I'm struggling to do it. I have been looking for it all around the internet for like a month but couldn't find much that I understand. I know a way to do it which is using Cookies but I don't really know how to code cookies, I just need some hints and help to do it. 
Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<form id="update" onsubmit="return false" method="post">
    <td><input class="rateContainer" value="Rate" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="rate"></input></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value ="Update" onclick="Update();" /></td>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function Update() {
    var Update = document.getElementById("rate").submit;
}
```

Comment: HTML and JavaScript are dynamic. They do not store data. To do that you have to use the browsers local storage or a server

Comment: There are a few options for you.  You could use PHP/MySQL, or you could simply use Local Storage.  Local storage is a lot like setting cookies.  Have a look at local storage it sounds like you could just add that to your function and be good!

Comment: See Jonas W's answer, that is pretty much exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See localStorage:

```
window.onload=function(){
var input=document.getElementById("yourinputid");
if(localStorage.getItem("input")){
//if there is a stored value, apply it to the input
input.value=localStorage.getItem("input");
}
input.oninput=function(){
//if input is changed, store it
  localStorage.setItem("input",input.value);
};
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I has really been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use cookies for it. Use `localStorage`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage